# Connection refused on heroku postgresql db via node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm running a postgresql database on heroku, via node. I have my server setup to post to '/submit', which calls a database controller to insert the data into the database. Everything works successfully locally, but when I deploy it to heroku and POST, I get the following error in my heroku logs.

```
2013-01-21T20:23:43+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/submit host=[MYDOMAIN].herokuapp.com fwd=[IP] dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=5ms connect=17ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=2
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]: node.js:201
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:637:18)
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
2013-01-21T20:23:46+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:646:11)
2013-01-21T20:23:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

and a 503 in the application.

Here's the relevant controller code (in coffeescript).

```
LOCAL_DB = "postgres://localhost:#{DBNAME}"

connect = ->
    db = process.env.DATABASE_URL or LOCAL_DB
    client = new pg.Client
    client.connect()
    client

insert = (options) ->
    client = connect()
    query = client.query "INSERT INTO #{TABLE} VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4);",
        [options.uid, options.ls_pref, options.hp_pref, options.date]
    query.on "error", onError
    query.on "end", -> client.end()
```

I did promote my database to DATABASE_URL:

```
$ heroku config | grep DATABASE_URL
> DATABASE_URL: postgres://[URL]
```

Why is my connection being refused?

Comment: May seem like a silly comment if I'm wrong, but I believe Heroku will also store a db password in your environment variables. Are you using that when you attempt to connect?

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the heroku docs about having to authenticate before connecting. Is there?

Comment: I am not sure, I haven't personally used Heroku's Postgres addon. I would recommend finding an example on the internet somewhere (perhaps take one from Heroku's docs), and once you have that working build on it to get what you need.

Comment: Ok. That's not very helpful, but I appreciate your help. I should note that I can query my database locally with `heroku pg:psql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't passing the database string when creating the client.

```
# Yes
db = process.env.DATABASE_URL or LOCAL_DB
client = new pg.Client db
client.connect()

# No
db = process.env.DATABASE_URL or LOCAL_DB
client = new pg.Client
client.connect db
```

The local database was working despite this rather obvious oversight. You've been warned!

Comment: I like this #yes #no convention, might copy it :)